# Meilisearch - Vue instantsearch limit search to one index

Tags: vue.js, meilisearch, vue-instant-search

I've got a small problem here with meilisearch and vue-instantsearch.

I've got some models amongst which are a model called `car-model` and a model called `manufacturer`. The relation of `manufacturer` to `car-model` is 1:n.

Now, the `manufacturer` -model has a field called `founder`. So if I take for instance the company `VW` I add the name `Ferry Porsche` to the founder field for that Model.

When I'm searching my indizes with meilisearch now, and I'm entering `Porsche` into my search box, I'm getting `Porsche` as a result for `manufacturers` but I'm also getting `VW` because for some reason vue-instantsearch also displays hits in the `founder`-attribute of the `manufacturer`-model.

According to `vue-instantsearch`s documentation I can limit the attributes that are being searched like so:

```
<ais-index index-name="manufacturer">
            <ais-configure :attributes-to-retrieve="['manufacturer']"> <!-- <-- this should in theory limit the results to hits only in model-->
              <ais-hits>
                <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
                  <h3>
                    <ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="name"/>
                  </h3>
                  <template v-if="item.logo">
                    <div class="hit-name__thumbnail">
                      <img :src="getImageUrl(item?.logo?.url)"
                           class="img-responsive search-box__results-manufacturer-logo"/>
                    </div>
                  </template>
                </template>
              </ais-hits>
            </ais-configure>
          </ais-index>
```

This however does not work and I'm still getting both `VW` and `Porsche` as a result for `manufacturer` in my results.
Is there something I'm missing here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

greetz
DeM

Answer (score 1):

According to the configure widget documentation of vue-instantsearch :

> the props have to use camel case since they’re directly forwarded to
> the Algolia API. In HTML or string templates, you can do this by
> adding `.camel` before the value of the prop.

So it should be:

```
<ais-configure :attributes-to-retrieve.camel="manufacturer"> <!-- or "['manufacturer']" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx, @CaroFG, this didn't solve my problem, however.

I got it working differently though, by using the meilisearch api directly and setting the searchable attributes on my model via a PUT request.
The solution in the webstorm HTTP-Client for that looked something like this:

```
PUT http://localhost:7700/indexes/car-model/settings/searchable-attributes
Content-Type: application/json

[
  "name",
  "manufacturer.name" # since name is a nested attr on the related manufacturer entity
]
```

Greetz, derelektrischemoench